# deploy nextjs13 vercel prisma

Tags: next.js, deployment, prisma, vercel, next.js13

throw this error:
ReferenceError: location is not defined
at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/901.js:416:66
at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/901.js:508:21
at exports.startTransition (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:27:267)

I am not using 'location' in my project

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR9fH.png)

I've been watching tutorials and reading official documentation for several days but I can't solve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.